# Include the whole content of another jar with maven dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven

I need to include the whole content of another jar into my jar. This is because I need to wrap the library that is not OSGi-compliant into OSGi container.

The affected library is Saxon-he and I've found a project that wraps it: https://github.com/lucee/osgi-bundle-saxon-he.git. Here is the maven dependency plugin used:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.10</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack</id>
         <phase>validate</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
                <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
                <version>9.7.0-10</version>
               <type>jar</type>
               <overWrite>false</overWrite>
               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
             </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
           <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
           <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
```

The problem is, that this solution doesn't pack everything. The XMLs from the root of the original jar are missing, and the exception is thrown when the library tries to read them...

I've tried to change the phase of the task, but without success... The solution works perfectly with java classes (afterwards, a maven-bundle-plugin is called, and all OSGi imports are generated correctly) but it fails when it comes to resources...

Any idea how to make it? Everything is unpacked into target/classes, but those stuff is not packed into target jar...

Comment: If you build your OSGi bundle with the org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin, you can configure which dependencies to embed with the Embed-Dependency config instruction. I don't know if it will include the XMLs you need, but you could give it a try. Documentation: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embedding-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

For your expected behaviour, you can use the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin.
In fact, as reported in the documentation, it will create a JAR that contains the binary output of your project plus the unpacked dependencies.

> Use jar-with-dependencies as the descriptorRef of your assembly-plugin
>   configuration in order to create a JAR which contains the binary
>   output of your project, along its the unpacked dependencies. This
>   built-in descriptor produces an assembly with the classifier
>   jar-with-dependencies using the JAR archive format.

For extra details, check [maven-assembly-plugin docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html)

Said so, you can configure it like the following:

```
<build>
...
    <plugins>
    ...
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
...
</build>
```